# Why "|" (or) in regex give weird result when used as replacement criteria

Tags: java, regex

First of all, I'm not an expert at regex. So please take a look at this regex :

```
([km]u|nya|[kl]ah|pun)$
```

I want to remove "nya" and "lah" in following string :

```
diserahkannyalah
```

Rather than show "diserahkan", its result is "diserahkannya". So, not all criteria satisfied when attempting replace operation.
Why is it happen? Im using Java and use replaceAll method from Matcher

Comment: If the string was `FOOnyaBARlah`, what is the result you would want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a quantifier:

```
([km]u|nya|[kl]ah|pun)+$
                      ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hF5pC3/1)

This `+` tells the regex engine to repeat matching the pattern the `+` quantifies 1 or more times. Here, the quantifier appears after a `)` that closes a capturing group, so, the whole capturing group pattern is quantified.

Note that if you are just removing all these substrings, you can make use of a non-capturing group: `(?:[km]u|nya|[kl]ah|pun)+$`.

See the [*Quantifier Cheat Sheet*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) for more details on regex quantifiers.

Comment: You're right. Thanks so much. It's really helping and so fast.

Comment: I'd like to add that `[km]u` and `[kl]ah` can match at the same location which is not a good idea when writing alternation groups. Although in this case it is not so important (no need to dive into "premature optimization"), just keep in mind that all alternatives inside a group should not match at one and the same location to ensure good regex performance.